# Is this the cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability

> A continuous random variable X takes positive values only and is such that $P(X>x)=k(2-x), 0\leq x\leq 2$. Find the expected value of $X$.

Is $P(0<X\leq 2)=k(2-x)$ the cdf, so I differentiate it to get the pdf and I can get $E(X)$ from there? I'm a bit confused because the definition of a cdf goes by $P(X\leq x)$ rather than $P(x_1<X\leq x_2)$.

Comment: $P(X>0)=1$ since $X$ is a positive rv. What can you conclude about $k$ from this?

Comment: $k=0.5$ I guess.

Comment: Correct. Are you familiar with $\mathbb EX=\int_0^{\infty}P(X>x)dx$ for positive random variable $X$?

Comment: Isn't $E(X)=\int_0^∞ xf(x) dx$? Where $f(x)=F'(x)$.

Comment: Yes that also, but the formula I mentioned can be proved for positive random variables and in this case it is convenient. If you are not familiar with it yet, then just forget my hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $P(X\le x)=1-P(X>x)= 1-k(2-x) = \mathrm{the \, CDF}$

And then you differentiate as you have said.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

For **every** nonnegative random variable $X$
$$
X=\int_0^X\mathrm dt=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{X\gt t}\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant t}\,\mathrm dt,
$$
hence

> $$
> \mathrm E(X)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm P(X\gt x)\,\mathrm dx
> $$

Comment: [+1] More information on (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13377)